# How do I get rid of lines not matching a timestamp via sed?

Tags: sed, grep

I am not sure why `sed` is not working as expected in this particular instance. I have lines of the form:

`12:42:46.675 token`

where I expect the timestamp to alwas have that format. Unfortunately every now and then there are lines in the file which do not begin with a timestamp and I want to get rid of those. I tried filtering out everything that does not match the above with:

`sed -n /^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}/p`

but the above filters everything out, even if I give `sed` the `-r` option. What is the correct way of doing that with `sed`? And is there an alternative with `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` to only display lines starting with timestamp format:

```bsh
grep -E '^([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3} ' file
```

Comment: +1 for the right approach. @PalaceChen - any time you find yourself describing your requirements in a negative way like "filter out everything that does NOT match" just take some time to think about how to express that in a positive way instead and it'll help you select the right tool and the right solution. In this case - you don't want to remove lines that do NOT match an RE, you want to select lines that DO match an RE so grep is the obvious tool of choice.

Answer (score 0):

`Sed` doesn't accept `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead. And both `{` and `}` are not metacharacters, they are literal for `sed` so you will need to escape them for the special behaviour, it would result like:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{3\}/p' infile
```

**EDIT**: Also surround the expression between quotes (better singles than double) to avoid shell expansion.